# Sticky Keys is functional but the beep-sound turns off and on so I don't know when it's on?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, ease-of-access

I always have Sticky Keys on but when when the right-side <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key kept working on and off I decided to restart the computer.  Now, I have to keep checking whether Sticky Keys is on because a few minutes after I turn on Sticky Keys the beep-sound that's supposed to be heard when pressing a Sticky Key disappears but the Sticky Keys function is still working but silently.  But now I never know whether it's on or off...what is going on?

Other thing is ever since the Sticky Keys started having the non-beeping problem
keyboard shortcuts aren't working.  For example, before <kbd>Win key</kbd> + <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> = maximizes current window but now it doesn't work.

Win 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to `Start->Control Panel->Ease of Access`.
- In the Ease of Access Center, you should see an option to "Change how your keyboard works", click this.
- Once you are on the next "screen', you should see an option to "Set up Sticky Keys", click this.
- Under Keyboard Shortcut, you should see a checkbox for "Make a sound when turning setting on or off"

You can also get to this menu by hitting your sticky key 5 times and then click the link "Go to the Ease of Access Center to disable the keyboard shortcut"

Comment: I already have all the boxes checked.  What should I do?